# Finite generations of a field $K$ are obtained by repeating extensions of four types

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

There are four types of finite field extensions described in Matsumura, Commutative algebra, Page 190. It is claimed that all finite generations of a field are obtained by repeating extensions of four types.

The four types are given by $L=K(t)$ where

1. $t$ is transcendental over $K$.
2. $t$ is separably algebraic over $K$.
3. If $K$ is a field extension of $k$ (not necessarily finite), and char($k$)=p, $t^p=a\in K$, $t\notin K$, $d_{K/k}a=0$.
4. Same as 3. but $d_{K/k}a\neq0$.

How do we know this is an exhaustive list?

Comment: Note that in the first case the field extension is not finite (but finitely generated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By choosing a transcendense base of the field extension we can reduce to the finite algebraic case using 1. So let $L/K$ be a finite extension. Let $F$ be the separable closure of $K$ in $L$. By 2. we are reduced to the case $K=F$, i.e. $L/K$ is purely inseparable. Now, any $x\in L\setminus K$ satisfies $x^{p^r}\in K$ for some $r\geq1$ and $p=\operatorname{char} K$. Choose any such $x$ and $r$ minimal. Then apply 3.+4. to $t=x^{p^{r-1}}$, so we can replace $K$ by $K(x^{p^{r-1}})$ and then repeat until $L=K$.
(Note that 3.+4. can be restated as $L=K(t)$ where $t\notin K$, $t^p\in K$, $p=\operatorname{char} K$ without mentioning $k$ or $d_{K/k}$)

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand it now. Can't understand how it leads to the following lemma however. Any ideas? 
Let $k$ be a field and $K$ an extension of $k$. Let $L$ be a finitely generated extension of $K$. Then ${\rm rank}_L \Omega_{L/k}\geq {\rm rank}_K \Omega_{K/k} + tr.d_L K$.
Any ideas?

Comment: Matsumura proves this when $L=K(t)$ for some $t$ as in the cases above. To deduce the general case from this we need to show that if the claim holds for $L/K/k$ and $L'/L/k$, it also holds for $L'/K/k$. We can then argue inductively. If you write out the inequalites for $L/K/k$ and $L'/L/k$, add them up and simplify we get exactly the claimed inequality for $L'/K/k$.